# Drupal via Eclipse for PHP - Errors in code documentation

Tags: php, eclipse, drupal, code-documentation

I have downloaded *Eclipse for PHP Developers* in order to manage Drupal code. To this end, I altered my Eclipse settings by following the descriptions on [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/75242#PDT) page, then created a new PHP project and referred to the existing Drupal project on my localhost webserver.
However, now I am confronted with thousands of errors, only occuring in documentation sections, as the one I copied below.
The error of those lines below is: **A cannot be resolved to a type** (lines 7 and 10). I assume this has to do with the lack of type-hinting, as it has been described [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/711918). Nevertheless, I am wondering how to cope with this issue, as the code I am trying to use is merely imported. Simultaneously, I want to use Eclipse as an IDE.

```
/**
 * Checks that the directory exists and is writable.
 *
 * Directories need to have execute permissions to be considered a directory by
 * FTP servers, etc.
 *
 * @param $directory A
 *          string reference containing the name of a directory path or URI. A
 *          trailing slash will be trimmed from a path.
 * @param $options A
 *          bitmask to indicate if the directory should be created if it does
 *          not exist (FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY) or made writable if it is read-only
 *          (FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS).
 *          
 * @return TRUE if the directory exists (or was created) and is writable. FALSE
 *         otherwise.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's just a problem of Eclipse configuration. There's a huge step by step on DO on how to configure Eclipse for Drupal development.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-eclipse

And there are others out, too.

Apart from that I'd rather recommend [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) for Drupal Development.

Comment: Those are the Eclipse settings I have been referring to above, thanks though. Nevertheless, thanks for the tip regarding PHPStorm. With the help of [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/drupal.html) guide, setting up my Drupal project was fairly easy.

Comment: @noai - Oh, I must have overread that. Sorry! And yes PHPStorm and Drupal is a really good team.